# Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to strin

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code. When I execute it it shows the error message "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string"
Please help me to solve this problem.

```
$sql = "SELECT dname FROM bdonor WHERE DID = 2";
$dname = $con->query($sql);
echo $dname;
```

Comment: That's because the  `query` method returns a result set, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to convert the **class** mysqli_result to **string**(obviously it returns error), try this..

```
$sql = "SELECT dname FROM bdonor WHERE DID = 2";
$result= $con->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
       echo $row['dname '].'<br />'; // here is the output display line by line
```

Comment: how can i return single record?

Comment: @prasanth single record in the sence..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function mysqli_result($res,$row=0,$col=0){ 
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($res); 
    if ($numrows && $row <= ($numrows-1) && $row >=0){
        mysqli_data_seek($res,$row);
        $resrow = (is_numeric($col)) ? mysqli_fetch_row($res) : mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        if (isset($resrow[$col])){
            return $resrow[$col];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```